# How can I log password entered to 'sftp' command?

Tags: logs, password, sftp

How can I log the password entered to 'sftp' command?

The command is shown in `.bash_history`, but obviously the password is not included as it comes as the next prompt. How can I also log what is entered to the `Password:` prompt?

```
sftp jonestom@sftp.sharebox.com:/ftp/jonestom
```

Comment: It might help to know why you want to do that - logging passwords is generally a massive security problem, and avoided by anyone who cares about securing pretty much anything. What's your underlying purpose here?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I log the password entered to 'sftp' command?

Basically you can't until you modify the source code of `openssh`. And you don't want to do this.

`sftp` is using secure shell (SSH), which reads the password sends it to the server and safely zeroes the memory where it was stored. This implies you should not be able to get the password, which is a good security practice.

Do you have some reason for it? You want to spy somebody?

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Kohne told, this is not secure at all.

For your testing, you can try `sshpass` package

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Then try

```
$ sshpass -p 'PASSWROD' sftp jonestom@sftp.sharebox.com:/ftp/jonestom
```

The line will be saved in your history

**Remember, take care about what you're testing.**

Comment: I don't want to have to prefix the `sftp` command. I want it to trigger whenever it is used.